# Event volunteers registration module

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a module for an event website which calls for volunteers to register by sending name/email.

Ideally, it would allow some users to access the registered volunteers database in some downloadable format (CSV for instance).

Is there something like this for D7? I've been googling but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module for this situation in the past.   Just create a name and email component!

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.